# How can I Print Multiple Page Image?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am developing winform application.
I have 5-6 different images stored in my "C:\temp" drive.
Now i want to retrieve all images and print all together.
For this i have tried below code in c#

```
objPrintImage = Image.FromFile("C:/temp");
objDimension = new FrameDimension(new System.Guid());

PrintDocument objPrintDoc = new PrintDocument();

objPrintDoc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(this.objPrintDoc_PrintPage);
if (objPrintDoc.PrinterSettings.IsValid)
{
    objPrintDoc.Print();
}
```

But i got error in first line only. Error says:

> illegal character in path

Comment: Try "C://temp" or @"C:/temp" /t indicates a tab.

Comment: @Jjj I have tried both, but got FileNotFoundException Error.

Comment: That's because you're saying an image == a folder. It's not. Read Stephan Bauers answer how this problem should be solved.

Comment: @Jjj isn't it a \, like `\t`? Not sure fwd slashes need to be escaped.

Comment: You're right ;) Can't edit it anymore :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the path of a **directory** to `Image.FromFile()` but this method expects the path of a **file**

Try to get all files inside your temp folder (e.g. via [`Directory.EnumerateFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles.aspx)`(@"C:\temp")`) and then pass the filepath (not the folder) to the `Image.FromFile()` method.